# Is changing the RDS master password drops current connection?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We know the procedure of changing the master password of RDS instance.
I want to know:
Does the RDS instance drop the current connections which were connected with old credentials or they remain in running state as in core MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot have `root` access to an RDS.
2. You can change the `master user password` of the RDS, provided during the creation of the RDS.
3. If this particular username is not in use anywhere and you change the password, there will be no connection drops.

Answer (score 0):

Connection didn't drop while changing the master password in RDS.

Also:
The change is applied asynchronously, as soon as possible. This setting ignores the Apply immediately setting.

You can check the RDS docs:
[RDS DOC to Modify RDS instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html#USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.Settings)